# Objective-C Naming Conventions - A Clarification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, naming-conventions

I have a doubt. Its not obvious for me.

Lets say we have a **@property** named **myProperty** in a class. We can do two things while synthesizing it. Either we can assign an **ivar**, say **_someIVar**, to it, or we can just simply omit it in which case the compiler takes care of creating an *ivar* with the same name, **myProperty**, for that property. In the first case we can access the property using the *ivar* **_someIVar**. In the second case we can use the *ivar* **myProperty** which was created by compiler for us.

Now my doubt is, when we push another view controller from a view controller which is already in the navigation stack, we use,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

As *navigationController* is a property, I assume that it should be having an *ivar* assigned to it. There are only two possibilities.

1) First one is Apple has the convention of naming the ivars with an preceding **underscore(_)**. If this is the case I can call the *pushViewController:animated:* method like this,

```
[_navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

2) Second possibility, obviously, is the ivar with no underscore,

```
[navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

But the compiler is not allowing me to access the navigationController in either way. Why? Is that something related to private properties or something or I just don't understand the Objective-C at all?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Don't try to break encapsulation. Instance variables are private for a very good reason. They are a implementation detail and can change every time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't know what Apple did to implement the navigationController property, so you cannot just assume there is a _navigationController ivar floating in the UIViewController class somewhere. Case in point: A property can be declared @dynamic, in which case the implementation can be absolutely anything at all.

There's no way to guess at the ivar backing a property just by looking at the property itself.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guess at the name of an ivar. What's more, you should not be trying to access ivars declared in superclasses. And thirdly, there's no guarantee that the `navigationController` property is backed by an ivar at all, it could be backed by a custom getter that calculates its value.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have the source to UIKit, so we cannot say definitively what the ivar is called.

However, Apple convention does seem to be _ivar.

What it seems like is that Apple has declared _navigationController (or whatever it may be called) as a private ivar using `@private`, which means that the ivar can only be accessed by instances of that class and not subclasses.

Also - that property is declared read-only, so you can't even try to write to it, meaning that Apple really doesn't want you to change it.

Note that you have more than two possibilities for ivar name.  A property can be represented by an ivar of any name.  If you look at the Apple documentation, they have an example:

```
@synthesize firstName, lastName, age=yearsOld;
```

> This specifies that the accessor methods for firstName, lastName, and age should be synthesized and that the property age is represented by the instance variable yearsOld.